# Почему sel в квадратных скобках?

Tags: javascript

```
function fuk() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('moi').selectedIndex;
    var options = document.getElementById('moi').options;
    alert('вы выбрали: ' + options[sel].text);
}
```

Comment: Потому что options - это массив а sel - ключ элемента в  массиве

Comment: А что такое ключ элемента?

Comment: @Dan_din в данном случае `sel` - это индекс (число), указывающий на выбранный элемент в массиве options.

Answer (score 4):

`options` - это массив элементов. `sel` - индекс элемента массива.